# convolution implementation in c++

Tags: c++, opencv, filter, convolution

I want to implement 2D convolution function in C++ by myself, without using filter2D(). I'm trying to iterate all pixels of input image and kernel, then, assign new value to each pixel of dst.
However, I got this error.

> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)

I found that this error tells I'm accessing nullptr, but I could not solve the problem. Here is my c++ code.

```
cv::Mat_<float> spatialConvolution(const cv::Mat_<float>& src, const cv::Mat_<float>& kernel)
{
//    declare variables
    Mat_<float> dst;
    Mat_<float> flipped_kernel;
    float tmp = 0.0;

//    flip kernel
    flip(kernel, flipped_kernel, -1);

//    multiply and integrate
// input rows
    for(int i=0;i<src.rows;i++){
// input columns
        for(int j=0;j<src.cols;j++){
// kernel rows
            for(int k=0;k<flipped_kernel.rows;k++){
// kernel columns
                for(int l=0;l<flipped_kernel.cols;l++){
                    tmp += src.at<float>(i,j) * flipped_kernel.at<float>(k,l);
                }
            }
            dst.at<float>(i,j) = tmp;
        }
    }
       return dst.clone();
}
```

Comment: I don't really know open cv but i think you need to initialise `dst`

Comment: Nothing in the question conclusively points to a problem in the shown code. Just because the shown code allegedly crashes doesn't mean it's where the problem is. C++ doesn't work this way. The real problem can be anywhere. Which is why you must show a [mre].

Comment: I modified to flipped_kernel.at<float>(k,l); and Mat_<float> dst; based on both of your advices. But I still have a same error. Any other point?

Comment: The issue is the line `dst.at<float>(i,j) = tmp;` because `dst` is not initialized. You can't assign something to index 5 if the matrix has no size/data. Instead, initialize the matrix as the first commenter said. `Mat_<float>` is not an initialization, it is a declaration. Use one of the initializations where you can specify a `cv::Size` or the rows/columns: https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#af1d014cecd1510cdf580bf2ed7e5aafc

Comment: @alkasm I copied src as 'Mat dst = src.clone()' and it worked. Thank you for your comment!

Answer (score 5):

To simplify let's suppose you have kernel 3x3

```
k(0,0) k(0,1) k(0,2)
k(1,0) k(1,1) k(1,2)
k(2,0) k(2,1) k(2,2)
```

to calculate convolution you are scanning input image (marked as `I`) from left to fright, from top to bottom 
and for every pixel of input image you assign one value calculated from the formula below:

```
newValue(y,x) = I(y-1,x-1) * k(0,0) + I(y-1,x) * k(0,1) + I(y-1,x+1) * k(0,2)
              + I(y,x-1) * k(1,0) + I(y,x) * k(1,1) + I(y,x+1) * k(1,2) + 
              + I(y+1,x-1) * k(2,0) + I(y+1,x) * k(2,1) + I(y+1,x+1) * k(2,2)


 ------------------x------------>
 |
 |
 |      [k(0,0) k(0,1) k(0,2)]
 y      [k(1,0) k(1,1) k(1,2)] 
 |      [k(2,0) k(2,1) k(2,2)]
 |
```

`(y,x)` of input Image (`I`) is anchor point of kernel, to assign new value to `I(y,x)` 
 you need to multiply every `k` coefficient by corresponding point of `I` - your code doesn't do it.

First you need to create `dst` matrix with dimenstion as original image, and the same type of pixel.
Then you need to rewrite your loops to reflect formula described above:

```
cv::Mat_<float> spatialConvolution(const cv::Mat_<float>& src, const cv::Mat_<float>& kernel)
{
    Mat dst(src.rows,src.cols,src.type());

    Mat_<float> flipped_kernel; 
    flip(kernel, flipped_kernel, -1);

    const int dx = kernel.cols / 2;
    const int dy = kernel.rows / 2;

    for (int i = 0; i<src.rows; i++) 
    {
        for (int j = 0; j<src.cols; j++) 
        {
            float tmp = 0.0f;
            for (int k = 0; k<flipped_kernel.rows; k++) 
            {
              for (int l = 0; l<flipped_kernel.cols; l++) 
              {
                int x = j - dx + l;
                int y = i - dy + k;
                if (x >= 0 && x < src.cols && y >= 0 && y < src.rows)
                    tmp += src.at<float>(y, x) * flipped_kernel.at<float>(k, l);
              }
            }
            dst.at<float>(i, j) = saturate_cast<float>(tmp);
        }
    }
    return dst.clone();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your memory access error is presumably happening due to the line:

```
dst.at<float>(i,j) = tmp;
```

because `dst` is not initialized. You can't assign something to that index of the matrix if it has no size/data. Instead, initialize the matrix first, as `Mat_<float>` is a declaration, not an initialization. Use one of the initializations where you can specify a `cv::Size` or the rows/columns from the different constructors for `Mat` (see [the docs](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#af1d014cecd1510cdf580bf2ed7e5aafc)). For example, you can initialize `dst` with:

```
Mat dst{src.size(), src.type()};
```